# Is it possible to divide an equilateral triangle into 12 congruent triangles?

Tags: geometry

Can you divide an equilateral triangle into exactly 12 congruent triangles?
interesting question i haven't yet been able to work on.
The sides can be of any length.

Comment: Can you divide *any* triangle into exactly 4 congruent triangles?

Comment: How about first dividing the triangle into 3 congruent triangles by joining the centre (centroid) to the 3 vertices, and then dividing the 3 smaller triangles into 4 congruent triangles the obvious way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a hint for one way to do it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "A hint"? Very nice answer. +1